# How many ways to color each cell of $2\times 13$ table with $4$ colors so that cells with a common side aren't the same color?

Tags: combinatorics

$2\times 13$ table cells can be painted red, blue, green and yellow. "Neighbor" cells with common sides must have different colors.

How many ways to do this are there?

Thanks in a lot advance!

Answer (score 1):

Find out in how many ways you can color the two leftmost fields $(1,1)/(2,1)$. Then assume that all fields $(1,j)/(2,j)$ $\>(1\leq j\leq r)$ have been admissibly colored, and find out in how many ways you can color the fields $(1,r+1)/(2,r+1)$. This will lead you to a simple recursion.

Answer (score 1):

There are $4\times3=12$ possibilities for the first column.

If $n\in\{1,\dots,12\}$ consecutive columns among which the first column have been painted then there are $1\times3+2\times2=7$ possibilities to paint the $n+1$-th bordering column.

This leads to $12\times7^{12}$ possibilities.

Answer (score 0):

A table with 2 rows and 13 columns can be interpreted as a graph where each cell is a vertex having edges to the cell beside it and below it.

If $(1,1)$ cell is marked as $\textbf{1}$ , $(1,2)$ cell is marked as $\textbf{2}$ and so on then the $(2,13)$ cell is marked as **26**.

[image]

Note that Vertex 1 has 4 choices. Vertices 2 and 14 have 3 choices each. Now vertex 15 has 2 choices (if 2 and 14 have the same color) or 3 choices (if 2 and 14 have different colors).

Then we proceed as follows:

- First Column in 12 ways:

  - Choose 1 in 4 ways.
  - Choose 14 in 3 ways.
- Adjacent Columns in $3^{12} \times 5^{12}$ ways:

  - Choose 2 to 13 in $3^{12}$ ways.
  - Choose 15 to 26 in $5^{12}$ ways:

    - 2 ways. Consider 2 and 14 have different colors, then we have $\binom{2}{1}$ colors to choose from, or,
    - 3 ways. Consider 2 and 14 have the same colors, then we have $\binom{3}{1}$ colors to choose from.

So we can choose in $12 \times 3^{12} \times {5}^{12}$ ways.

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $1,3,\ldots 15$ all have to have the same color.  That was not specified.

Comment: I stated 4 colors in the post, thanks anyway

Comment: @Ross right... I hadn't considered that.